# Sublime Text 4: show word count for selected text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext4

I recall that when selecting a block of text in Sublime Text the status bar used to display the *word* count. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1100839/133149) confirms that I recall correctly, Sublime Text 3 used to show that information:

[image]

I'm running Sublime Text 4 (Build 4143) and this information is no longer displayed. Only lines and character counts are shown:

[image]

Is this feature hidden in the settings somewhere or did ST remove it entirely? If so, why??

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WordingStatus , you can try a package

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the packages that count words. I am asking about a very useful feature that came integrated with the editor and that apparently was removed for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime does not and has never had this power without a plugin. Seen below is a screen shot of the last version of Sublime Text 3 with no settings or packages and some text selected.

The counts displayed are for the selected lines and characters, but not words; there is also no setting in the core that enables this.

[image: Sublime Text 3 image of selected text]

The answer you linked is to a question where someone is asking about the WordCount package itself, and in particular asking about how to apply a setting. The answer states that you just need to select text to see counts in the status bar without having to set any setting, which is true:

[image: Sublime Text 3 with the WordCount plugin installed]

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't realized that the question I linked was discussing that package and I was sure that feature was present in ST at some point